# how many free space are there within ibdata1

Tags: mysql

When **innodb_file_per_table** is off, **ibdata1** will keep growing even if you drop tables or delete rows, but there should be some available free space there when you drop tables.
How to know how much free space left within ibdata1?
How many space are used by real table data and how many are used by meta data?
When you do 'delete/drop ' operation will it store transaction logs within ibdata1?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
mysql> show table status like 'mytable'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: mytable
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Dynamic
           Rows: 2049
 Avg_row_length: 16663
    Data_length: 34144256 <-- space in the clustered index (that is, the data)
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 81920    <-- space in secondary indexes
      Data_free: 4194304  <-- space in full free extents
```

The data_free is always in multiple of 1MB. This is because it doesn't count free space unless it's an extent of 64 contiguous free pages. There might be more free space, in small amounts hiding among partially-full extents, but there's really no way to report these.

The data_free reports the amount of free space in the tablespace the table occupies. For tables that were defined when innodb_file_per_table was enabled, the free space is for the respective tablespace. For tables that are sharing the system tablespace or general tablespaces, the data_free is reported for each table, but the information is duplicated. They all describe the free space in the same shared tablespace, so don't sum it up.

You can also check it this way:

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.files where file_id = 0\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             FILE_ID: 0
           FILE_NAME: ./ibdata1
           FILE_TYPE: TABLESPACE
     TABLESPACE_NAME: innodb_system
       TOTAL_EXTENTS: 76
         EXTENT_SIZE: 1048576
           DATA_FREE: 34603008
                 ...
```

Again, notice that the data_free is an exact multiple of the extent size. Free space that is not in a contiguous extent is not reported.

```
mysql> select 34603008 / 1024 / 1024;
+------------------------+
| 34603008 / 1024 / 1024 |
+------------------------+
|            33.00000000 |
+------------------------+
```

When you DELETE, copies of the deleted rows are stored in an "undo tablespace." If you rollback the transaction for the DELETE, the rows are restored. In older versions of InnoDB, the undo tablespace was always ibdata1. So if you did UPDATE or DELETE of a very large amount of data in a single transaction, it would expand ibdata1. The space would be freed when the transaction committed and the copy of old row versions was no longer needed. But as you know, ibdata1 would never shrink.

In modern versions of MySQL, the undo tablespace is in a separate file, not ibdata1. So you can truncate the undo tablespace periodically if it grows too large. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-undo-tablespaces.html for details.

Comment: when i execute "select * from information_schema.files where file_id = 0\G" it shows nothing, did i do it wrong?

Comment: and since there is only a few GBs space left in the disk, i want to do a lot of deletes/drops to free up some space for further data insertion. will that help? or the 'delete/drop' operation will use more space in ibdata1

Comment: I got the examples above from MySQL 5.7.28. Different versions of MySQL may implement this information differently.

Comment: DROP will not add more space to the ibdata1. DELETE might, because it can be rolled back therefore it has to copy the old data somewhere. There might be free space in ibdata1 to use, or if not, it will expand ibdata1. I can't predict that for your case.

Comment: At this point, I would set up a replica on another server, **make sure it uses innodb_file_per_table**, and follow instructions in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-setup-slaves.html to dump data from the master (your current instance) and import it to the replica.